# Как при попадании на сайт открыть пользователю сразу 5 окон (5 URL's)?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, редирект, скрипт

Есть сайт-страница https://redmap.site/index32.html , при заходе на которую - юзера должно редиректить через 5 секунд на сайт https://google.com .

Во время этих 5 секунд - должны открываться в отдельном (маленьком) окне 5 сайтов , вот по этим юрлам:

```html
https://alpha.com
https://betta.com
https://gamma.com
https://delta.com
https://lambda.com
```

и должны все эти 5 окон закрываться через 1 секунду.

На данный момент как и нужно - срабатывает через 5 секунд редирект на страницу гугла, и во время этих 5 секунд происходит открытие самого верхнего юрла и закрытие его через 1 секунду. Только этот (самый верхний) url открывается сейчас:

```html
    https://alpha.com
```

Почему не открываются другие юрлы по принципу, открылись на 1 секунду и закрылись?

Код страницы: **index1.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>redmap.site</title>
  <!--[if IE]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <style>
   article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer,header,
   hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
  </style>

<script type="text/javascript">




partner_window1_alpha = window.open("https://alpha.com", "partner", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=5000,left=5000,width=100,height=100");
setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window1_alpha.close();
  location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}, 5000);


setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window1_alpha.close();
}, 1000);


partner_window2_betta = window.open("https://betta.com", "partner", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=1000,left=1000,width=100,height=100");
setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window2_betta.close();
  location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}, 5000);


setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window2_betta.close();
}, 5000);


partner_window3_gamma = window.open("https://gamma.com", "partner", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=5000,left=5000,width=100,height=100");
setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window3_gamma.close();
  location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}, 5000);


setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window3_gamma.close();
}, 1000);


partner_window4_delta = window.open("https://delta.com", "partner", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=5000,left=5000,width=100,height=100");
setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window4_delta.close();
  location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}, 5000);


setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window4_delta.close();
}, 1000);




partner_window5_lambda = window.open("https://lambda.com", "partner", "menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=5000,left=5000,width=100,height=100");
setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window5_lambda.close();
  location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}, 5000);


setTimeout(function() {
  partner_window5_lambda.close();
}, 1000);

 


setTimeout(function() {
  location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
}, 5000);
</script>

 
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Hello world </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как открыть пять окон и сгореть в аду за такое надругательство над пользователем.

Comment: изучаю в теории как реализуется открытие таких окон